# unable to insert data from excel

Tags: php, mysql

To upload excel data to mysql database
when i print don't know why its displaying like this some one help to overcome this

```
     <form action="uploademails" id="bannerForm" name="SmsfeeFrm" method="POST" class='form-horizontal' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="box-body" style="display: block;">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Upload file<font color="red">*</font></td>
                                <td>
                                 <input tabindex="10" type="file" name="file" id="file"  class=""/>
                                <span class="pull-left">
                                        Allowed types are .jpg,.png and .jpeg only <br><i>Recommended Size : 1920px(W) x 551px(H) </i>
                                    </span>

                                </td>
                            </tr>                                       
                            <input type="hidden" id="banner_id" name="banner_id" value="<?php if($_EditStatus){ echo $_EditBannerData[0]->banner_id;}else{echo "0";}?>" />                              
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>

        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
                          {

                            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                             {
                                 print_r($emapData[1]);
                                   /*  $data = array(
                                        'SUBJ_CODE' => $emapData[1],
                                        'SUBJ_DESCRIPTION' => $emapData[2],
                                        'UNIT' => $emapData[3],
                                        'PRE_REQUISITE' => $emapData[4],
                                        'COURSE_ID' => $emapData[5],
                                        'AY' => $emapData[6],
                                        'SEMESTER' => $emapData[7],
                                        ); */

                             }exit;
                            fclose($file);
                            //redirect('welcome/index');
                          }



    When i print getting data like this

    D���"�5<���qFzel������}E���F���b?�SQ���*��q7C�;��+�}��ݧ�;4pDZ���    �K(�N��h�wŘQ��6�㶷 [SYJ�(��p��»�g�>�X_�x���wu�{���\>k�]X���y�}�钣�M�26PsFnJ�'K��U�z�<�{���E�Uϲ���V���)�9�Z[��4^kd�5���!J���?��Q�3�qBo�C~���M����m<�.�vp�����IYӦ���Z�Y_p���=al-�Y�}Nc�͙���ŋ4vja��vl����'S�&�A�8�|�*~x������1%M0�g%����<���ҭ���PK!����#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels��Mj�0F���A̾������-d�MI �%��8���9�H6zE�[='��ޜSS�t����ߣ���PK!�JK-�xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml�P�J�0��C��MWY���"&4�S�~�aY]^{�[�E%B�:�a�5���30$�R썤0�������z����V��8�?��ո�z�c�$�7���� UѸ������誘�~8��V���h<5%䩜�c=������O�s}��U_�jК��W�?�k;Iw��FX1   5��Ml]`�Ѧ�<�����9� �P��tEL�ʳP�H��8��_�_��PK!C['���xl/sharedStrings.xml���J�0E��!�ݤ�Eٕ4[���ЎM����Tܿ7E�>�{ϝƜ>�V��B�w����/v��xR���3��XH�Xa��EhUyEa�0J��{G�X�g�u�� ]9]\�E�pWJ���l�_�+��CG��@z������#-�*O��8���y1f��@/~Q���o�s4�������C6j0��{urS|���&d�q���Z���PK!]�@a"xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml��Ko�0����?�*��E��X�u��bӱ��$%i��(iQc-vI$�O�H�����k����h2�)���w�����%J��b��!�o��}����$�^5�`�^e��zXE�*蘚�z��BvL�V�"5H`�u��(��E�1�Sa%�'��k^£(����2������늣�D$�}HV�%��%��pRk���Z(5Tx��¶B���b����Dd��G�@�f�H�x9�-Ĭy����{���U������.I甔�E��Y�wl�L�|-ŉ��b]j`晒�*���"�\�1���s.�ڊK[2�m.m��E��@L�@9��G��U�̢��������@��^�jnQA΅юQ���n�WQ��R[�l�Ic�ڑg�Z~=�D��{ٜ��>�'�f��Y  ]��Nr�A��taS�����ZdH&��������L-Rl ��8"`!j�f.%��'
```

What am doing wrong.
What i have missed or what am doing wrong.Tried a lot still no luck 
when i print don't know why its displaying like this some one help to overcome this

Comment: `Allowed types are .jpg,.png and .jpeg` ? If you only allow images then why are you trying to process csv files? Is the file a csv or xls?

Comment: that is just test need to upload xls or csv only

Comment: can you add the csv data or was this an xls file?

Comment: trying to add emails.xlsx

Comment: xls and xlsx etc are very different to a plain csv file. The fact that Excel can read a csv file is trivial - it is essentially a structured text file but xls and xlsx are totally different and you cannot read them using `fgetcsv` ~ you would need to use either `COM` objects or some other library for handling xls files

Comment: might be of interest: https://github.com/PHPOffice/Phpexcel